# get_terms - only top level

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I am trying to get only top level term:

```
$cat_args = array(
    'parent '       => 0,
    'number'        => 10,
    'hide_empty'    => false,           
);

$categories = get_terms( 'question_category' , $cat_args);
```

But this query return all childterms too, I tried everything but it always get child terms too.

I am trying since last 5 hours and can't find whats wrong in my code, is this a WP bug or there is something wrong in my code ?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: I think you mean only top level terms from your taxonomy `question_category`

Comment: Yes I mean that

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your code is correct, well almost correct. On first view, I must confess, I missed it too.

You have two syntax errors in your code. If you look closely, `'parent '` and `'parent'` is not the same. You should not leave blank spaces between single quotes (`'`) and arguments.

Also, you don't need to add a `,` after your last argument.

This should work

```
$cat_args = array(
    'parent'        => 0,
    'number'        => 10,
    'hide_empty'    => false           
);
```

### EDIT 15-06-2016

As from WordPress 4.5, the syntax has changed for `get_terms()`. The `taxonomy` parameter is now included in the array or args, so the new use will look like this

```
$args = [
    'taxonomy'     => 'my_tax',
    'parent'        => 0,
    'number'        => 10,
    'hide_empty'    => false           
];
$terms = get_terms( $args );
```

Comment: Just a note: you don't *need* to add `,` after last array argument, HOWEVER, **it is a good practice to do so** ;)

Comment: @jave.web Thanks for that, I know that, I just don't always do that. ;-)

Comment: @jave.web It's actually *not* good practice to add a `,` after the last array argument, as this will break other languages which arent as tolerant to redundant commas. Eg. JSON will break if you do this.

Comment: @Mikepote that is actually not true, it is good practise and if you are trying to move code from one language to another, you should use proper conversion/ter. It is like saying you can't have object creations and/or variables  as arguments, because if you copy/paste it breaks JSON... 
It is good practise even in JavaScript, therefore the support was added later on everywhere. *Copy/paste inside the same language and project is much more probable and adding the trailing comma if possible prevents common slow-downers* - that is not only from my experience, but also from experience of others.

Comment: @Mikepote To tack on to what jave.web is saying, it's not only good practice but specifically recommended in the WordPress PHP Coding Standards, which ideally all WordPress-specific code should follow: https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/#indentation

Comment: I stand corrected.